# Display Object in Flash Frame Animation and Frame Code

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am in learning in flash, I have a problem now
I made a symbol `movieClip` object in the background layer / Lower list
and add some `actionscript` code in layer,just to show the `movieClip` in that layer ,

```
stage.addChild(new anyObject());
```

when test the movie , the object is show in the foreground not in the background,
how can i fix this problem , I have a tween animation in the top of layer before
but now it covered by that object and the animation is complex too

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will answer your question:

```
stage.addChildAt(object,level);
```

Comment: I use the object at level 0 if I use at level 1 the object is covering the animation scene too,the object now in background
but when I add a background contain image,and now I have 3 layer
a background image layer in the lower,the object in the middle layer,and the animation in top of the layer.

but when I test the movie,the background Image is covering the object.
or is possible to addChild a layer, so I can arrange the layer in actionscript

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand what your saying, but perhaps this link will clear up your questions about object levels: http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2008/03/29/understanding-howas3-manages-depths/

Comment: ah , thank you before 
i make a mistake ,now my problem is solved ,
i using your answer